# Why is toctree not updating with RTD theme?

Tags: makefile, python-sphinx, read-the-docs, autodoc, toctree

I have an programmatically generated sphinx-doc source that uses the Read-The-Docs theme. The source tree looks like:

```
source
├── conf.py
├── index.rst
├── models
│   ├── 1lin
│   │   ├── 1lin_Amplero.rst
│   │   ├── 1lin_Blodgett.rst
│   │   ├── 1lin_Bugac.rst
│   │   ├── ..
│   │   ├── figures
│   │   │   ├── 1lin_all_PLUMBER_plot_all_metrics.png
│   │   │   ├── 1lin_all_PLUMBER_plot_distribution_metrics.png
│   │   │   ├── 1lin_all_PLUMBER_plot_standard_metrics.png
│   │   │   ├── Amplero
│   │   │   │   ├── 1lin_Amplero_PLUMBER_plot_all_metrics.png
│   │   │   │   ├── 1lin_Amplero_rank_counts_all_metrics.png
│   │   │   ..  .. 
│   │   ├── index.rst
│   │   .. 
│   ├── 2lin
│   │   ├── 2lin_Amplero.rst
│   │   ├── 2lin_Blodgett.rst
│   │   ├── 2lin_Bugac.rst
│   │   │   ..  
│   │   ├── index.rst
│   │   .. 
├── model_search.rst
├── sphinx_static
│   ├── jquery
│   │   ├── AUTHORS.txt
│   ..  ..
├── sphinx_templates
│   └── layout.html
..
```

`index.rst` includes a TOC like:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 2

    model_search

    ...
```

and `model_search.rst` includes all of the model `index.rst`s:

```
.. toctree::
    :maxdepth: 1

    models/1lin/index
    models/2lin/index

    ...
```

When I initially build the source with `make html`, it builds nicely, and creates a TOC that includes all of the existing models.

However, when I add a new model (e.g. `3lin`), and then `make build` again, the TOC is not regenerated on the pages for the existing models (`1lin`, `2lin`, etc). The only way I've found to correctly re-create the TOC on all pages is to either modify the `conf.py` (e.g. enable/disable `autodoc`), or to manually `touch` all of the relevant `.rst` files.

Should the TOC be regenerating on the old model pages, or is this expected behaviour? If it should be happening, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's expected behavior. Sphinx builds only files that have not changed since the last build. You can `touch` each file, or you can run `make clean` before running `make html`.

Comment: So basically because the TOC actually forms part of the individual model index pages, it won't update? Whereas if the TOC was a separate frame or something, it would?

Comment: Yes to the first question. Each output page has its own copy of the ToC, so the ToC only gets re-built on pages that are rebuilt. For the second question, I don't know... I guess it would depend on how the system is built.